# How to hide username and password in log file when using CLI DataLoader?

Tags: data-loader, security-review, encryption, passwords

When using the Dataloader command-line, if the value of parameter sfdc.debugMessages is defined as TRUE then debugging SOAP messages are captured. In the log file generated I can see both the user and the password.
If I set the value of sfdc.debugMessages to FALSE no logs are recorded. I want to record the logs as per my business requirement. 
My question is; whether there is any way to hide the user/password. Please suggest!

Comment: Same issue here :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=command_line_import_data.htm&language=en_US) sfdc.debugMessages will log SOAP message debugging. As login is one of the message that need to be exchanged it also log that with all input(user/pass) and output (session id,server urls, etc)

Now SFDC do have provision of filtering messages. At lest it not clearly documented. Which leads us to use other workarounds.

So, I can think of 2 workarounds for this:

1) Data loader source is available on [GitHub](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/tech-pubs/2011/12/data-loader-source-now-on-github.html). Modify the source code to filter out login messages from debug output.

2) Modify the process.bat (or write wrapper around it) which will process the log file and strip user/pass from the log.

Some thing like this:

```
set str=teh cat in teh hat
echo.%str%
set str=%str:teh=the%
echo.%str%
```

out put:

```
teh cat in teh hat
the cat in the hat
```

More option for string replace are available at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir